# Nested arrays in Strong Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, strong-parameters

Faced a strange problem or bug.

i have a route with strong parameters method:

```
def st_params
  params.permit([:id, logs: [], metric_ids: []])
end
```

Then i call it with, for example, rspec:

```
post some_path(format:json, metric_ids:[ [1,0,1], [5,1,4] ])
```

And when i call a st_params method there is no metric_ids param and i have got message in logs: Unpermitted parameters: metric_ids

But if i change st_params method like this:

```
def st_params
  p = params.permit([:id, logs: [], metric_ids: []])
  p[:metric_ids] = params[:metric_ids]
  # or just p = params.permit!
  p
end
```

Now, everything works fine in browser, but it looks strange.

But in rspec i have received nil value for metric_ids in any case :( I have not found any information about the problem. Maybe someone here may help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

2 things that may be causing your trouble here:

1) The bang method `permit!` is for accepting an entire hash of parameters and it does not take any arguments. I also am unsure if `permit!` can be called on the entire `params` hash, the documentation is unclear on this.

2) Your use of array notation may be causeing the `params` hash some confusion. (It also may be acceptable, but looks a little unorthodox compared to what I'm used to seeing.) I would write your `st_params` as

```
def st_params
  params.permit(:id, :log, :metric_ids)
end
```

Also, a permit argument like `metric_ids: []` as you have written will whitelist any parameters nested inside of `params[:metric_ids]`, based on the way you are passing data to this hash above, I do not think this is your intended usage. It appears that you are storing an array at this level of the hash and there is no further complexity, so no need to whitelist params beyond this scope.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for response. I fixed my missprints above. If i do as you have adviced i still get message: Unpermitted parameters: metric_ids. The problem fixes when there is no array inside metric_ids array like: metric_ids: [1,2,3], but not metric_ids:[[1,2,3]]

Comment: @AndreyEremin Were you able to find any solution to missing params? My params are also getting lost

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem. Appending `as: :json` to `post` solved the problem for me.

Ref: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1700#issuecomment-304411233